# Porque obtengo una imagen que parece en negativo cuando uso el metodo ImageChops.difference

Tags: python

Simplemente tomo dos imágenes y las resto mediante el método ImageChops.difference.
La imagen resultante parece estar en negativo, aunque no lo es.

Yo esperaría ver en la 3er foto el objeto distinto entre las 2 primeras imágenes con los colores originales.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageChops

im1 = Image.open("C:/CapturasPantalla/2021-08-31 100402/1.jpg")
im3 = Image.open("C:/CapturasPantalla/2021-08-31 100402/3.jpg")

box=(80,180, 525,435)
im1=im1.crop(box)
im3=im3.crop(box)

diff = ImageChops.difference(im3, im1)

diff.save("C:/CapturasPantalla/2021-08-31 100402/1-3.jpg")
diff.show()
```

Comment: Y cuál es el error?? Ese es el resultado de la imagen. ¿Qué es lo que esperas?, revisa [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida

Comment: El script termina sin error. Y de hecho, obtengo la imagen de lo que deseo, sin embargo, no tiene los colores correctos.

Comment: Agrega las imágenes y elimina la publicación que has puesto como respuesta